# how to connect and writestream the postgres jdbc in my spark 2.4.7?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

```py
df5.writeStream.format("jdbc").option("url", "url")\
  .option("dbtable","test").option("user","postgres")\
  .option("password", "password").start()
```

always getting the

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o112.start.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source jdbc does not support streamed writing
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message clearly says the reason for the error: `Data source jdbc does not support streamed writing`

So if you want to write data to JDBC sink from the structured streaming, you need to use [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) instead, something like this:

```py
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    df.format("jdbc").option("url", "url")\
      .option("dbtable","test").option("user","postgres")\
      .option("password", "password").save()
  
df5.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

Comment: what is epoch_id and df

Comment: `df` - dataframe for the current batch, `epoch_id` - identifier for the batch, See linked documentation

Comment: sorry i didn't get please provide any example for this

Comment: what do you mean? these are just parameters to a function that are passed by the `foreachBatch`.  If your JDBC code works in batch mode, then it will work with structured streaming as well

Comment: i also having the code but i don't know the which parameter to pass epoch_id and df def write_pn_report_to_postgres(df, epoch_id):
    df.write \
    .mode('append') \
    .format('jdbc') \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/coviddata") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "PASSWORD") \
    .save()

windowed_report_df.writeStream
   .foreachBatch(write_pn_report_to_postgres) 
   .option("checkpointLocation", 'checkpoint')
  .outputMode('update').start()

Comment: You don’t need to pass parameters yourself - they will be passed when stream is started.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
def _write_streaming(
    df,
    epoch_id
) -> None:         

    df.write \
        .mode('append') \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres") \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
        .option("dbtable", 'test_table') \
        .option("user", 'user') \
        .option("password", 'user') \
        .save() 

df_stream.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(_write_streaming) \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

You need to add ".awaitTermination()" at the end.